# PHP Function not returning replaced string when using variable

Tags: php, string, function, variables, str-replace

I am having trouble using a function for replacing text in my string, here is the function:

```
function decodeString($string){
$foo = "foo1";
$string = str_replace("foo",$foo,$string);
return $string;
}
```

I am accessing it from another page and the PHP file the function is in, is included before I try to use it.

```
decodeString($var1);
```

When it returns, the replacement is empty, so it just removed the word "foo", whereas if I don't use a variable in the replace function ($foo), and instead enter the text as a string there so "foo", then it returns with the text there, why can't it be returned if it's a variable?!! Don't understand this :(

Comment: I didn't find nothing wrong in your code, what is your $var1 value ?

Comment: The function itself [works](http://3v4l.org/JK8IE) as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The best and the recommended way to replace a string is to set a constant in the string, then using the str_replace function, for example:

$result = str_replace("[FIND]", "foo1", "This is my [FIND]");

Working example:
function.onl/str_replace("[FIND]", "foo1", "This is my [FIND]");

[Demo](http://function.onl/str_replace(%22[FIND]%22,%20%22foo1%22,%20%22This%20is%20my%20[FIND]%22);)